# Se cierra la sesión ssh en MobaXterm y WinSCP después de estar inactivo durante unos minutos

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Bueno el problema que tengo es que cuando inicio sesión vía ssh en MobaXterm todo bien cuando estoy dentro del terminal pero si lo dejo un momento sin hacer nada durante unos minutos se cierra

Sesión detenida - Presione para salir de la pestaña - Presione R para reiniciar la sesión - Presione S para guardar la salida del terminal en un archivo Error de red: el software provocó la interrupción de la conexión

Y por otro lado en WinScp también se cierra porque está inactivo y me sale el error Host is norcommunicating for more than 15 second y tengo que reconectarme. Esto es muy molesto si estoy teniendo otros trabajos en paralelo, lo curioso esto es que esto no pasa cuando estoy en mi oficina y solo cuando estoy en casa, no sé si es mi red de internet/módem o el firewall de mi computadora, ¿es normal? Agradecería sus aportes por favor.